# Here, is 'for' optional? and 'so' is exactly the same as 'so that' and 'in such a way that'?

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's a context.

> I ordered a product and it was delivered two days ago. But the design of the product was not what I had in mind. I asked ***for*** the restaurant's name to be printed larger than this and the restaurant's phone number was supposed to be written on the bottom, ***so*** customers could see it to make a reservation.

Q1. Here ***for*** is optional?

Q2. Here, ***so*** is the same meaning as ***so that, in such a way that*** and I can use whichever I want without changing meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Q1: No, "for" is not optional. With a little thought, most people would grasp the meaning of "I asked the restaurant's name", but as it's written, it seems you're actually asking a question to the name of the restaurant. Plus, when you ordered the product, you actually asked "for" something.

Q2: If I'm understanding your question correctly, yes, "so" is a proper substitute for that phrase and does not change the meaning.